# Where can I find pre-published AD&D modules/adventures?

Tags: game-recommendation, adnd-1e, published-adventures

I will soon be running a AD&D first edition adventure with a group of friends. AD&D is very new to me, so I am not completely comfortable with the system, and I have little time to prepare an adventure. For those reasons, I chose to play a pre-published module/adventure instead of designing one of my own. Where on the internet can I find such modules/adventures?

Comment: This question does not fit our game-rec requirements because there are hundreds, thanks to @Nagora for providing the right kind of answer to it.  You could change this to "how do I find these" to keep this reopened and get more answers of that sort, or narrow it down to where three might be a single or much shorter set of correct answers with a lot more requirements.

Comment: Is this better? I'm not sure if the question really contributes to the website though, as it is probably a duplicate now. I can delete it, if you judge it necessary.

Answer (score 1):

There are various such modules on Dragonsfoot.org:

[Dragonsfoot modules](http://www.dragonsfoot.org/ad/)

There's also a [meta-thread](http://www.dragonsfoot.org/forums/viewtopic.php?f=1&t=60382) which lists a lot of info on adventures grouped by level.